# Party Blowers to Noisemakers?

Tags: plastic, kids-crafts

I went to the store to get a couple packs of party horns for a Bible story in Sunday school.

[image]

However, I did not realize that they were actually party blowers that did not make any noise until I got home, which is not as entertaining for the kids and is irrelevant to the story.

Is there any way to modify these to make noise? I know they are really cheap, but I'm the kind of guy that will sand cast and weld jewelry before going to James Avery.

Comment: Is the package open? If not, the easiest solution is to exchange them. The blowers don't have the reeds that are present in noisemakers so I'm not sure that converting them is even possible.

Comment: @Catija I'm trying to avoid going back to the store; I already got everything else I needed. Also, I have more tools and supplies then the adverage household. I could make a metal whistle with everything I have if I wanted to. Making things is a lot more fun then doing the adult thing.

Comment: I wanted to do something similar with straws. http://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/1736/24

Answer (score 1):

My computer won't let me see the picture, so this answer might not be helpful. Assuming we're talking about the regular party blowers, the only issue with trying to add a reed to make noise are space and ability. There's not that much space for it to go, only about an inch in the plastic tip, but the tube is very small. Second is actually getting it in there. Putting it in the hole then trying to attach it would be hard since most of them are glued together, and you can't pull of the tip. Unless you can figure out a way to build a reed that's small enough, and get it in there, you might have to get back and buy some other ones.

Comment: I was unable to see the picture, but Im pretty sure were talking about the regular party blowers.